# Excel will paste the last thing copied in Excel, not the most recent thing in the clipboard (pic included)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016, copy-paste, clipboard

I am trying to copy data from another program and then paste it into excel. If I have previously copied something in Excel, and the green flashing border is still visible, it will paste what I had previously copied in excel rather than what I had copied from another program (even though that is what I copied most recently).

This problem is prevalent across all programs that I am copying from; it has to do with excel.

The thing that I have copied from the other program do show up on the clipboard in excel.

Here is a picture for an example

[image: excel clipboard]

The last thing I copied in Excel was "$0", but then I copied "27,400" and "5,050". When I go to paste in excel, "$0" pastes. If I paste into any other program, "5,050" pastes.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Press the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get rid of the selection box.

Comment: I don't want to have to press esc before I copy anything into excel. I am looking for a setting that I can change so Excel recognizes what is in the clipboard. Thank you, though.